# ESP32 Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). when using BLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, decoder

I am developing on ESP32 WROOWER using Arduino IDE.

When I use BLE in my sketch it bricks down, I dont know why. My sketch is big, 1416000 bytes and in Tool>Partition Scheme I selected "HUGE APP 3MB....".

Here is the backtrace:

```
    Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 0 register dump:
PC      : 0x401d084e  PS      : 0x00060930  A0      : 0x800d7080  A1      : 0x3ffd35f0  
A2      : 0x3ffe3b84  A3      : 0xca5091d7  A4      : 0x3ffc6234  A5      : 0x3ffd39f0  
A6      : 0xca5091d7  A7      : 0x3ffbb9cc  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffd3870  
A10     : 0x3fff273c  A11     : 0x3fff273c  A12     : 0x00060320  A13     : 0x3ffd39f8  
A14     : 0x3f29b3ec  A15     : 0x3f29b3ec  SAR     : 0x00000018  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x0000000c  LBEG    : 0x4000c349  LEND    : 0x4000c36b  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  

Backtrace: 0x401d084e:0x3ffd35f0 0x400d707d:0x3ffd3610 0x400d62de:0x3ffd3630 0x400d66b9:0x3ffd38e0 0x400d9720:0x3ffd3900 0x400d9b95:0x3ffd3950 0x400d90cd:0x3ffd3970 0x400d7249:0x3ffd39d0 0x4014389a:0x3ffd39f0 0x4013d5f6:0x3ffd3a30 0x40090ee5:0x3ffd3a60
```

And when I use decoder here is what it shows to me:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS5kr.png)

When I test BLE using Examples it works fine, but when I combine it with my sketch it fails...

If you know how to fix this please help me!

Answer (score 5):

Check the following:

- Do you use String Class and do a lot off String constructions with String c = "a" + "b"
- are you creating char arrays on the fly e.g. char d[] = "efg";
- are you using delay() - get rid of it its blocking

If there is one Yes than you've found the reason, if its 3x No we need your code (github, pastebin) to do further analysis

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I fixed it somehow, I am not sure how but there is no more that problem, but there is another one;

Comment: > "If there is one Yes than you've found the reason"
Can you elaborate on why these would cause this issue?

Comment: "than you've found the reason" elaborating a bit on what the actual problem is would be useful...

Comment: Using String class or creating char arrays on the fly leads to memory fragmentation. Since there is as of now no garbage collection mechanism for the esp32. This means even if the absolute fre memeory looks sufficient eg. 8000 bytes, but divided into 80 a 100 byte large fragments, a string with 101 bytes "kills" the Esps  process and leads to crash. Use of delay triggers watchdog routine and there you go (or crash). If a mor detailed elaboration is needed, we have to do it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I put noInterrupts() at the start of a function and left an exit that was not covered by interrupts().
When that exit was taken ......blam!!